# Drools Nested Accumulate

Tags: drools

This calculates the average temperature of EACH sensor:

```
rule "Average"
when
  $s : Sensor()
  accumulate( Reading( sensor == $s, $temp : temperature );
              $avg : average( $temp )
            )
then
  // print average of EACH sensor
end
```

I then want to get what sensor has the maximum "average temperature", I was trying something like this, but it is obviously incorrect:

```
rule "MaxAvg"

when
  accumulate ($s : Sensor()
              accumulate( Reading( sensor == $s, $temp : temperature );
                          $avg : average( $temp )
                        );
              &max : max($avg)
            )
then
    // print sensor with max "average temperature"
end
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off if you create facts from the averages per sensor and use a second rule for determining the maximum.

```
rule "Average"
when
  $s : Sensor()
  accumulate( Reading( sensor == $s, $temp : temperature );
              $avg : average( $temp ))
then
   // print average of EACH sensor
   insert( new Average( $s, $ave ) );
end

rule "maxAverage"
    salience -100
when
    Average( $s: sensor, $a: average )
    not Average( average > $a )
then
    // sensor $s has max. average $a
end
```

The second rule might fire repeatedly as Average objects are inserted unless something is done. I have used salience but there are other approaches.